# How to initialize the splitter handle position?

Tags: c++, qt, splitter, qsplitter

I want to initialize the splitter handle position like the following instead of in the middle. I cannot set it in the property.

[image]

How to solve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `QSplitter::setSizes` in this why to reposition the handle:

```
ui->splitter->setSizes(QList<int>() << 100 << 200);
```

Answer (score 16):

You should set the horizontal stretch for the two widgets in the splitter. For instance by setting the horizontal stretch of the left widget to `1` and the right widget to `2`, the right widget gets a width 2 times the left one :

```
leftWidget->sizePolicy().setHorizontalStretch(1);
rightWidget->sizePolicy().setHorizontalStretch(2);
```

Another possible way is to use `QSplitter::setSizes`.

Comment: You can do this in Designer as well, set the Horizontal Stretch property for each of the contained widgets

Answer (score 6):

Use `QSplitter::setStretchFactor(int index, int stretch)` where `index` is the position of the respective widget.

Answer (score 0):

i was having the same issue but ull find a predefined attribute existing called

```
`self.horizontalLayout_6.setSpacing(0)`
```

u will also find a

```
  self.verticalLayout_6.setSpacing(0)
```

u can change the spacing to whatever u like it worked for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).