# How to add vertical splitter for Viewer and QScrollArea?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Viewer contained inside a QFrame like this:

[image]

The white area is `Viewer` and grey area is `QFrame`.

What is want to have is another `QscrollArea` with the Viewer layed out vertically with a **vertical splitter** like this:

[image]

But even after selecting both `QScrollArea` and `Viewer` and then clicking the layout vertically in splitter button. The splitter does not appear? Any idea as to how to achieve this?

Comment: Does it not appear in the Qt Designer or when you run the program?

Comment: @ni1ight When I run the program

Comment: Could you make a screenshot of the Object Inspector in the Qt Designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer you're looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28313475/1839954

On a **not** layed out area, add the children widgets, select them with CTRL key pressed and **then** lay them out using a vertical splitter (there's a button on the layout toolbar above the form preview)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by "viewer" you mean a QListView for example, i had no problem to define this using Qt Designer. You should select the QFrame and the QScrollArea from the object inspector and then click on the vertical splitter layout inside Qt Designer.

Here is the result :

[image: UI]

Here is my object inspector :

[image: object inspector]

Hope this helps.